# can not install grub into sdb2 ext4 expansion usb drive

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have 2tb expansion drive which I partitioned it into two filesystem, **ntfs** and **ext4**. Both of them are primary filesystems. When I insert  expansion intu usb, it appears under `/dev` like `/dev/sdb1` for ntfs and `/dev/sdb2` for ext4.
I want to install ubuntu xenial into `/dev/sdb2` but I can not install grub on `/dev/sdb2`.

At first I mounted it under `/media/expansion`

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb2  /media/expansion
```

and

```
 sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --boot-directory=/media/expansion /dev/sdb2
```

but I get

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be  installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I checked partition table

```
gdisk -l /dev/sdb | grep -A4 '^Partition table scan:'


Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

How can I install grub into `/dev/sdb2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should install the bootloader to the head of the drive, in this case /dev/sdb (not to the partition, but at least it used to be possible, PBR instead of MBR). Is that really what you want? In that case why? If that is the case, maybe the second partition is too far away from the head of the drive for grub to see it. I have read about a limit at 137 GB.

So I would recommend that you install the bootloader to /dev/sdb

It will make it possible to boot from the external drive without involving the internal drive, /dev/sda. I would guess that this is what you want.

Comment: thank you for responding. I did `sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --boot-directory=/media/expansion /dev/sdb` and it installed grub into sdb successfully but how can I chainload it in grub?

Comment: setting uuid of sdb2 partition will do it?  Like `menuentry "Boot From USB" {
    set root=UUID=0437-401B
    chainloader +1
}
`
in /etc/grub.d/40_custom

Comment: From where do you want to chainload it? Maybe this link will help you? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus from default grub menu I use currently. I want to add menu item in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` in my system to chainload the grub in usb expansion I just managed to install.

Comment: Then it should work according to that link. I have used it in several computers to chainload to external drives. A simple alternative is to run the master system (with the grub from where you want to chainload) and execute 'sudo update-grub' with the external drive connected. It should find the Ubuntu system in that drive automatically.